# Emacs CEDET Hook

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet

I want to hook CEDET modes to c++ mode. I am using the following script in my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ...
        (my_cedet_load)
        )
      )
```

where

```
(defun my_cedet_load ()
  (interactive)
  (semantic-mode)
  (global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode t)
  (global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode t)
  (global-semantic-idle-completions-mode t)
  (global-semantic-highlight-edits-mode t)
)
```

Now, the problem is that once I open a .cpp file, the semantic-mode is enabled in all buffers. How do I only enable such mode in only .cpp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic is a **global** minor mode. From `semantic.el`

> To enable Semantic, turn on `semantic-mode', a global minor mode (M-x
>   semantic-mode RET, or "Source Code Parsers" from the Tools menu).  To
>   enable it at startup, put (semantic-mode 1) in your init file.

As such when you do `semantic-mode` it is enabled in all buffers. You can use `semantic-inhibit-functions` to restrict the buffers in which `semantic` is activated. From the documentation

> List of functions to call with no arguments before Semantic is setup.
>   If any of these functions returns non-nil, the current buffer is not
>   setup to use Semantic.

Below is an example of using this variable. it would instruct `semantic` to be activated only in `c-mode`, `cc-mode` and `java-mode` buffers

```
(add-to-list 'semantic-inhibit-functions
                 (lambda () (not (member major-mode '(java-mode c-mode c++-mode)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the key lies in the `global` word.
So use `semantic-stickyfunc-mode` instead of `global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode` etc.

### UPDATE:

Try this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-hook)

(defun my-c++-hook ()
  (semantic-mode 1)
  (semantic-stickyfunc-mode 1)
  (semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
  (semantic-idle-completions-mode 1)
  (semantic-highlight-edits-mode 1))
```

Comment: The problem is that when I do I get an error: 'error: Buffer *scratch* was not set up for parsing'

Comment: That means that you're calling it in `lisp-interaction-mode-hook` for some reason. Just put the contents of `my_cedet_load` into the hook.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Here it is:
    `(defun my-c-cedet-load ()
      (interactive)
      (semantic-mode)
      (semantic-stickyfunc-mode)
      (semantic-idle-scheduler-mode)
      (semantic-idle-completions-mode)
      (semantic-highlight-edits-mode)
    )`